# add table row and data from input field in that row

Tags: jquery

I have a table and a form with 2 input fields.

once user type in input fields and click save...it goes to table row.

now user types again and click save...it replaces old entries.

I am to add a new row with new text in input field which user types just before clicking save.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table1">
    <thead>
        <tr class="info">
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Access</td>
            <td>Delete</td>
            <td>Edit</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="info">
            <td class="mac-id">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="nameofUser">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="access">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="btn-delete"><a href="#" class="trash-icon">&nbsp;</a></td>
            <td class="btn-edit"><a href="#" class="edit-icon">&nbsp;</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-new">New</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-save">Save</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-cancel">Cancel</a>
</div>

    </table>
```

Jquery

```
$(".btn-save").click(function(e) {
    var macID       =   $("#mac-address").val(this);
    var nameofUser  =   $("#user-name").val(this);
    var access      =   $("#access option:selected").text(this);

    $(".table1 tr:last").after("<tr class='info'><td>&nbsp;</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/UFCeh/

Comment: So what problem are you having?

Comment: when I put some text in input field and click save...it create new row but does not insert text which i typed in input field.

Comment: You have some HTML issues. Here's a fiddle with them cleaned up: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/UFCeh/1 See if you can add your form fields and get a demo working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to add the input values into your code:

```
$(".btn-save").click(function(e) {
    var macID       =   $("#mac-address").val();
    var nameofUser  =   $("#user-name").val();
    var access      =   $("#access option:selected").text();

    $(".table1 tr:last").after("<tr class='info'><td>" + macID + 
        "</td><td>" + nameofUser + "</td><td>" + access + "</td>" +
        "<td class='btn-delete'><a href='#' class='trash-icon'>&nbsp;</a></td>" +
        "<td class='btn-edit'><a href='#' class='edit-icon'>&nbsp;</a></td>");    
});
```

Errr, actually the `this` within that code is pointing to the save button. So remove that too.

Comment: This problem is solved..Thanks Mottie. now edit button which is in the last <td></td> is not working now. i have a working on click of this button.

Comment: Oh, you didn't share that code. Try using the [`on()` delegate method](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). So it'll look something like this: `$('.table1').on('click', '.btn-edit', function(){ /* edit it */ })`. Same goes for the delete button.